# Insert a hash into the url of custom posts to make them function as anchors

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation

I have custom posts functioning as sections of a front page, and I would like to jump to them with anchors.

I have this:

```
example.com/about
```

I want this:

```
example.com/#about
```

So far, I have removed the slug from the custom posts, with `'with_front' => false`.

I would appreciate any hint how this could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution.

First I have assigned a slug to the custom post type:

```
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => 'something',
    'with_front'            => false,
    'pages'                 => false,
    'feeds'                 => false,
);
```

The I use a filter and a regex.

```
function 1234_filter_custom_post_url( $url, $post ) {
    if ( 'my_custom_post_type' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $url = preg_replace('/something\/(.+)\//', '#$1', $url);
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', '1234_filter_custom_post_url', 10, 2 );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link

> post_type_link is a filter applied to the permalink URL for a post or
>   custom post type prior to being returned by the function
>   get_post_permalink.

Comment: Very messy, certainly would not recommend this :)

Comment: @trainoasis So what would you have recommended?

Comment: @MereDevelopment heyo, don't have much context around this anymore as I'm not developing on WP anymore. If I had to give it a shot right now, I'd use WP only as data source and provide a custom Vue/React SPA to display the data as needed - hashes should be easy there using basic router libs :)